# How to know SmtpClient Host of my comany's email?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, smtpclient

I tested sending email from gmail with the code below. It works well.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.Port = 587;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "mypassword");
client.Send("mymail@gmail.com", "anothermail@hotmail.com", "Test Send Email", "Good Job");
```

But i want to change from gmail to my company's email. My email address at company like mymail@companyname.co.th. Then i change my code with the code below.It does not work.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.companyname.co.th";
client.Port = 587;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mymail@companyname.co.th", "mypassword");
client.Send("mymail@companyname.com", "anothermail@hotmail.com", "Test Send Email", "Good Job");
```

I think it was wrong at this line.

```
client.Host = "smtp.companyname.co.th";
```

**How to know SmtpClient Host of my comany's email?**

**Or what am I doing wrong?**

Sorry for bad english skill.

Comment: Ask your IT/email administrator.  It _might_ be available as a DNS entry, but equally your email could bounce around all over before it goes out onto the public internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me, not sure about if it'll work for you.

1) Open CMD and type in:

```
nslookup
```

2) This will return DNS server name and IP. Next type:

```
set type=mx
```

3) Finally type in:

```
companyname.co.th
```

You should get your SMTP server name back. For the record, my company's SMTP server name is not the same as it's domain name.

Answer (score 0):

The best guess is to do:

`dig MX smtp.companyname.co.th`

If you don't have dig installed, you can use an online tool, like: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#MX/

Select only MX records.

Comment: I always use [swaks](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/) to send messages before put the parameters in the code. It is easier to test the smtp capabilities and authentication.